# Validating Security Token issued by STS while calling WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

We have extended `SecurityTokenService` provided by `Windows Identity Foundation` (WIF). It issues token as expected and the SAML token is added in the SOAP header while calling every other WCF service we have.

I can see correct values in the `NotBefore` and `NotOnOrAfter` Saml Conditions present in the security token.

But surprisingly every call to other WCF services succeeds even when service is called after the time stamp present in `NotOnOrAfter` Saml condition that's present in the security token in the SOAP header.

1. I do not understand why it happens. Do I need to write some code to reject the call having expired security token?
2. Do I need to create custom binding or behavior for  it?
3. Does not WIF or WCF take care of this basic thing automatically?
4. Great if you could point me to some good documentation that explains things happening under the hood !

I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: Just a guess:  Does your WCF services use sessions?  I wouldn't necessarily expect the token to be re-evaluated for expiration in the middle of a session.

Comment: We don't use sessions...

Comment: I this a WS-Federation (web page) or WS-Trust (active client) scenario?

Comment: @Grzegorz Wilczura : We do not have any web pages. We have WCF services which are secured using STS. Client is a WinForm application which authenticates user with STS, gets security token and call other WCF services.

Comment: @Grzegorz Wilczura : Using .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This validation is provided by `SecurityTokenHandler`.
Which token handler is used depends on your token type and your configuration.

Answering your points:

1. This depends on token handler. For saml tokens this should be done for you.
2. Usually - No.
3. Like in point 1.
4. I personally dissasemble Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll.

Check your web.config for `<microsoft.identityModel><service><securityTokenHandlers>` section. If it is changed and You use custom handler than you might have overriden the default behavior implemented in `SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken`.
If not then You have to figure out your token type. If it is SAML1.1 or SAML2.0 then it should be validated. If not then please share your token type.

Answer (score 0):

Call to wcf service will rejected after ValitTo date expires plus time from MaxClockSkew parameter.
You can manage this parameter by configuring service.